# .on change function works first time not second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have a shopping cart that calculates cost and shipping based on quantity and weight. Because of this there are two possible shipping options and I have a function to auto-select the correct shipping on page load. However, if a person changes the quantity the function to select the shipping must run again.

To do this I tried this code:

```
$('.cartInputText').on('change', function() {   
    $('#ShippingOptions option').each(function(){
        if (this.value == '163182') {
            $('#ShippingOptions option[value="163182"]').prop('selected', true)
            return false;
        }
        if (this.value == '163183') {
            $('#ShippingOptions option[value="163183"]').prop('selected', true)
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This works the first time I change the quantity. If I change the quantity a second time it doesn't work. How do I fix this so no matter how many times I change the quantity it works?

**Update**

The onchange event fires the first time but does not fire the second time. Why?

Comment: Could you post a fiddle here?

Comment: @chris97ong - A fiddle wouldn't replicate how my CMS loads and renders the shopping cart unfortunately.

Comment: Which version of jQuery you use? 1.7 or 1.9.

Comment: Do you have a chance to bind event to document? I mean the difference between live and on in version 1.7

Comment: $(document).on('change','.cartInputText',function(){}); more like this.

Comment: @OQJF - That worked. Please post as your answer and, if you can, explain why that works and my code wouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use live instead of on, or if the version of jQUery is higher than 1.9, please make you code like this: `$(document).on('change','.cartInputText',function(){});`

For your sample code, you only bind the function to .cartInputText, if the page re-renders or whatever the reason cause `.cartInputText` re-generate, it loses the function.

For my code, I bind the function to document and I think you know the event of html element can bubble, you click on `.cartInputText` and it bubbles up to document and let the function be triggered. More, please check Live and Bind difference in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the help! With your explanation it makes sense. What happens is my CMS is running code that changes the totals of the cart, etc. and would be why it was losing the function.

Comment: It's my pleasure to give you this help. Np.

Answer (score 1):

User `KeyUp` function instead of `change` for detecting input text.

Like:

```
$('.cartInputText').keyup(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Here's the [official jQuery documentation for .keyup().](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/Z5L5B/)

Answer (score 0):

the above code works for the html code which is  added before executing the previous statements,

if  some other content with the same class (cartInputText) is added dynamically 
you need to assign above functionality by calling it again after adding the content.